# Is there a Run or command-prompt command that changes the background image in windows?

Tags: windows, command

example..Run/cmd desktop.exe http:www.tinypic.com/blabla.jpg -s

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: You could write a simple appication for that. The application can use the SystemParametersInfo(..) API. Is this what you are asking for? There is no, AFAIK, command that can be used to change the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't exist. You're going to have to write a script or full-fledged application to do this. I'll be happy to help you, if you can tell me whether or not this is acceptable, and if you have a language preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command line utility reg.exe to do that. you have to modify the registry value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper
```

Or you can create a file (say c:\foo.reg) with following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"wallPaper" = "path_of_new_wallpaper"
```

and process it from cmd line as:

```
regedit.exe /s c:\foo.reg
```

Setting the registry value isn't enough on all the flavor of windows os. You might have to reboot the machine for the changes to take effect. (I think there must a workaround to make it effective without rebooting the machine, but I have no idea about it).